# How to synchronize HLS and/or MPEG-DASH videos on multiple clients using ExoPlayer?

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, mpeg-dash

I'm trying to guarantee synchronization between multiple clients using DASH and/or HLS. Synchronization between each client must fall within 40 milliseconds.

Live streaming seems to be an obvious choice. However, the only way to really get within a small time frame of synchronization would be to lower the segment times. Is this the only viable solution? Are there any tags that would help me keep clients within 40 milliseconds to the live time?

Currently, I'm using FFMPEG to encode video and audio to live content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of separate issues here:

- 'Live time' - assuming the is the real time the event actually happens that is being broadcast, for example the actual time that a football is kicked in a game, then achieving a full end to end delivery to a end screen within 40 milliseconds is pushing the boundaries of any possible delivery technology. Certainly HLS and DASH streams won't give you that.
- Your target may be to have each end user be no more than 40ms different than each other end user - e.g. every user receives the broadcast with a 10 second delay, but that delay is the same plus or minus 40ms for each user. This is still quite a tricky problem as, unless you have some common clock that all the devices are synched to, you will be relying on some mechanism to signal the position in the stream between each device and some central or distributed control mechanism and, again, 40ms is not a lot of time to allow even for small messages to travel back and forth along with any processing required to calculate any time difference and adjust.

Synchronising internet delivered media streams is not an easy problem but there is at least some work you can look at to help you get some ideas - see here for some examples: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51819066/334402

Comment: Hey Mick! Thanks for the response. Using a mechanism to signal the position in the stream means that the device would have to sync if it is outside the 40 ms range. This means it would have to seek to a position. Unfortunately, when you seek to the clock time, you'll always be behind by the amount of time it takes to seek. Each device may take different amounts of times to seek, which means they still never truly are in sync. Do you have any thoughts on this? Also, thanks for the link! I'm trying to assess the feasibility of synchronization for HLS or DASH, these are good alternatives.